# Blender armature screwing up rig hierarchy in ue4

Tags: rigging, armature, unreal-engine

I'm trying to export a rig to Unreal Engine 4 and have it match the hierarchy of the default ue4 rig. The issue is that the armature shows up in the hierarchy.

This is what it looks like in blender.

[image]

In unreal this ends up being *HeroTPP > root > pelvis > etc*. when it should be *root > pelvis > etc*.

How do I get it so that the root bone is the actual root of my rig so that the hierarchy matches up with the one in unreal?

Comment: I have absolutely same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The unreal engine devs were aware of this issue and have made it so that unreal just ignores the extra root that blender creates when you import so the problem should be fixed now for everyone importing rigs into unreal.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `Hero TPP` -> `root`.  To do this, `Ctrl`+ click on the `Hero TPP` object on the outliner.

It shouldn't interfere with the actual bone named `root`, because one is on the Object level, the other on the Bone level.

Comment: That doesnt work because unreal reads it as a bone so it wont even import. Is there are way to move stuff around in the hierarchy or delete without breaking the rig? This rig seems to have an armature inside of an armature. Unreal reads the second armature as null and doesnt include it but it includes the first one.

Comment: I could rename the armature to root and delete the rootbone but I'm not sure what effect thats going to have on the animations when using rootmotion.

Comment: So as it turns out this looks like its a bug in the newer blender versions. I tested the same rig in 2.74 and it exports properly without the armature being a bone.

Comment: @KrunkFu - if it's a reproduceable bug, please make sure to file a bug report. Further explanations here: http://archive.blender.org/development/report-a-bug/